# How to more effectively ventilate a portacabin

Tags: ventilation

My son is sleeping in a portacabin that we didn't originally intend to be used as a spare bedroom and only has a single window at one end (no opportunity for cross flow ventilation).  Particularly in the Summer the air in the room gets distinctly stale when he's been in there for some time.

We live in a temperate climate where air conditioning is seldom used.

The simplest modification would be a passive 15cm vent through the wall (I'd presume at floor level for more opportunity for convective air flow) at the other end of the room.  I'd appreciate hearing any opinions as to whether this would be likely to make any useful difference?

Answer (score 1):

It will make a difference. A fan inside the cabin would improve that difference.  However, the difference will depend on temperature, wind etc.  Also bear in mind that if he is a teen, they tend to be sweaty.

I would try a fan inside first.  Then do the vent.

Answer (score 1):

A floor level vent will absolutely make a difference. If you're game for a little bit more modification, you can add a roof vent, then make a foam plug for the inside to use when you don't want the vent open. I did that on a shed once and it worked a treat.